# Symfony 2.7 minifying assets

Tags: symfony, uglifyjs

I'm trying to minify JS and CSS files using Uglifyjs and UglifyCss. I used this link :

[Symfony documentation](http://Uhttp://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/uglifyjs.html)

Here are the steps I made :

- Install **Node.js**
- Install uglify globally ==> **npm install -g uglify-js**
- **Set up of filter** as below :

  ```
  # Assetic Configuration
  assetic:
  filters:
  cssrewrite: ~
  #closure:
  #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
  #yui_css:
  #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
  uglifyjs2:
      # the path to the uglifyjs executable
      bin: C:/Users/Jonathan Housieaux/AppData/Roaming/npm/uglifyjs
  ```

Here is my template code :

```
    {% javascripts 'web/js/*' filter='uglifyjs2' %}

        <script src="{{ asset('reptika_slick.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('scrollvertical.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('menu_main.js') }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

Unfortunately, these files did not work anymore. I presume there is something I missed but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Start by selecting the 2.8 documentation instead of the current documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/assetic/uglifyjs.html.  Symfony 3.0 was just released yesterday which means that the 'current' documentation links are not longer applicable to Symfony 2.x.

Comment: I checked it out but I can't see any difference with the 2.7 documentation.

Comment: I assume that the indentation of your assetic configuration is only missing in this post and not in your actual config file?

Comment: Yes, the indentation exists in my project